# Masking and then pasting two images in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have an image which looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert the background to white and all the other pixels to black so that my image look likes this:

[image]

Let's say the original image is `img` and the above result is `mask`. When I try this to get the `mask` from the original image, things don't work as expected. I did this:

```
mask = np.ones_like(img)*255
mask[img > 0] = 0
```

Ideally I should get the expected result but this is what I am getting instead.

[image]

Also, I have another image which looks like this:

[image]

I want to paste the expected mask on this final sunset image. How can I do that using numpy/scipy/PIL/skimage?

Comment: Looks like one of your original colors used only one color channel, so for instance an RGB color like `(0,45,0)` became `(255,0,255)` - bright purple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are looking to get anything that's not black in `img` to be set as zero in `mask`, just look for `ANY` along the three channels (last axis) and use that boolean array for masking into `mask` -

```
mask[(img>0).any(-1)] = 0
```

Output for given sample #1 -

[image]

To mix it with the sunset image `img2` -

```
from scipy.misc import imresize

mask_resized = imresize(mask, size=img2.shape)
out = (mask_resized==255)*img2
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: And what about the second part? How to paste this mask on the sunset image?

Comment: Also, what does `-1` in `any()` signifies?

Comment: @mlRocks You want to use the mask of bikes image onto the second sunset image?

Comment: @mlRocks That's basically `.any(axis=-1)` i.e. use `ANY` along the last axis.

Comment: I want to paste this mask on the sunset image such that we can see the sunset image in the background and the mask also appears on it

Comment: The effect would be somewhat similar to this: https://www.123rf.com/photo_16115276_man-standing-on-the-beach-in-front-of-an-orange-sunset.html

Comment: @mlRocks Got this - http://i.imgur.com/KZGl780.png Would that work for you?